# Determine confidence level in guesstimate: gas stations in Germany

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, estimation

I read in the internet about the following guesstimate during a job interview for a trading position:

Give an estimate for the bid-ask on the number of gas stations in Germany (with max spread of 10 %). Tell me how sure you are, that your answer is correct. Afterwards, allowing unlimited spread, give a bid-ask so that you are 80 % sure.

The guy just gave an estimate and randomly said he was 30 % sure. So obviously he failed. I am very interested in how to approach such a question. Not particularly in how to arrive at the estimate, but how to define the level of uncertainty. My thoughts on that are the following:

Let's say that I think that there are 5 gas stations in my town with 20.000 inhabitants, but it might also be 3 or 7, I am not sure. So I arrive at an estimate of 5 +- 2 gas stations per 20.000 inhabitants, which accounts to 20k +- 8k in Germany. My PDF might be gaussian

$\mathcal{N}(\mu=20k, \sigma=8k)$.

Since we want a spread of max. 10 %, we are looking for the values of the PDF at 20 +- 5%, which gives us a confidence of ca. 10 %. For a confidence level of 80 %, we would need a bit more than 1 $\sigma$, so I would estimate a ask-bid of 30-10.

Is this general idea to answer this question legit or am I completely off?

Comment: This post raises some questions.  But first, what is a "bid-ask spread" on an estimate?  There seems to be some translation error here.  Then, why do you use a Gaussian to model your guessing?  How exactly do you manage to narrow the uncertainty without using any other information whatsoever?  That looks (more than) magical.

Comment: The term bid-ask spread refers to the lower and upper price limits at the stock exchange (it was an interview for a trading job). So I assume, the interviewer referred to the lower and upper bound of the estimate i.e. the confidence interval. I chose a Gaussian, since I thought it fits to my confidence level better than for example a univariate distribution (high certainty near the mean with an exponential decay). I have no mathematical verification for this approach, but I have no idea how to approach this question otherwise.

Comment: The concept of a bid-ask spread on the market is well known, thank you.  The difficulty I have is that it simply does not apply to something like a "count of gas stations." This makes the entire question incomprehensible.  I was hoping the problem was merely a matter of translation, but perhaps it goes deeper than that.

Comment: I believe that my interpretation of the bid-ask spread in the context of the problem is correct - and even if it isn't, I am interested in how to approach the problem, where the bid-ask spread refers to the upper-lower bound of the estimate.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot make sense of the last two paragraphs in this post, so I cannot suggest any possible approach.  The question seems to be asking for something impossible: if your uncertainty in the number of gas stations is wide, such as give or take $2/5=40\%,$ then *there is nothing you can do* to narrow that uncertainty, short of making additional assumptions or collecting data.